# How to handle a space in a JS string using charAt

Tags: javascript, string, charat

I am making a news ticker that converts text strings into graphic letters. The letters are drawn using a canvas. The function that creates the letters works perfectly except for one thing: It can't handle spaces in the strings that I pass to it.

Here is the function for converting the strings to their graphical forms:

```
function conv_string(str) {
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str.charAt(i).toLowerCase());
    make_letter(str.charAt(i).toLowerCase(), i);
    }
}

conv_string('New Brushes');
```

This function is pretty simple, it just takes each character in a string and passes it to another function (`make_letter();`), along with that character's position in the string. Right now, it will render the word "new" correctly, however it stops when it gets to the space. The `make_letter();` function works fine. [Here is the current fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u3ez6gu/13/).

Here is the `make_letters();` function:

```
function make_letter(letter, pos) {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    var w = parseInt(getComputedStyle(c).width);
    var h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(c).height);
    var full = Math.floor(h / 16);
    var gap = 0.65;
    var unit = full - gap;
    var capH = (full * 5) - gap;
    var inv = {
        a: [
            [0, 2],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 3],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        b: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        c: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        d: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        e: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        f: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0]
        ],
        g: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        h: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        i: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 2],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 2],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        j: [
            [0, 4],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 2],
            [3, 1],
            [2, 1]
        ],
        k: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [1, 3],
            [3, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        l: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        m: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [1, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        n: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        o: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        p: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 0],
            [4, 0]
        ],
        q: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 3],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        r: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 4],
            [4, 0]
        ],
        s: [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 0]
        ],
        t: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 2],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 2],
            [4, 2]
        ],
        u: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3]
        ],
        v: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 1],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 2]
        ],
        w: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 0],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 4],
            [3, 0],
            [3, 1],
            [3, 3],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        x: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 4],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 3],
            [3, 1],
            [4, 0]
        ],
        y: [
            [0, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 2],
            [4, 2],
            [1, 3],
            [0, 4]
        ],
        z: [
            [0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [0, 3],
            [0, 4],
            [1, 3],
            [2, 2],
            [3, 1],
            [4, 0],
            [4, 1],
            [4, 2],
            [4, 3],
            [4, 4]
        ],
        exc: [
            [0, 2],
            [1, 2],
            [2, 2],
            [4, 2]
        ],
        spc: []
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < inv[letter].length; i++) {
        var x = inv[letter][i][1] * full;
        var y = inv[letter][i][0] * full;
        if (pos == 0) {
            var xpos = x;
        } else {
            var xpos = x + ((pos * full) * 5) + (full * pos);
        }
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(xpos, y, unit, unit);
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

I believe the problem lies with how charAt is handling the spaces. As you can see I've tried to log the value returned from `charAt();` in the console, however when it finds the space, it just returns a blank space. How can I get a real, tangible value from this string when it finds a space?

If you take a look at the `make_letter();` function, you'll see it relies on a comparison from the values it receives from the `charAt();`. Thus if a space is encountered, I need to be able to compare it to values I have set in an object, but how do you compare a blank space against another value? Is there something else besides `charAt();` that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the problem lies with how `charAt` is handling the spaces. As you can see I've tried to log the value returned from `charAt();` in the console, however when it finds the space, it just returns a blank space.

Yes, that's it's job. `charAt` gives you the character at a given position.

> How can I get a real, tangible value from this string when it finds a space?

You can use `charCodeAt` to get the character code.

> Thus if a space is encountered, I need to be able to compare it to values I have set in an object, but how do you compare a blank space against another value?

There's nothing special about comparing spaces. However, there *is* something special about using a space as a property name, as you may want to in your `inv` object. At the end you have:

```
spc: []
```

...which creates a property with the name `spc`. Which isn't, of course, the same as a space. You *can* create a property with a space if you like:

```
" ": []
```

Similarly, nothing `charAt` gives you will ever match this:

```
exc: [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [4, 2]
],
```

I don't know what `exc` is meant to be, but if it's `!`, then:

```
"!": [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [4, 2]
],
```

You can use *any* string as a property name in an object initializer, you just have to put it in quotes.

Comment: It seems like it would be better practice to use the charCodeAt method. I'll probably use that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DigitalBrent: I'd probably go the other way if it were me, using `" ": []` and `"!": [...]` (I'd probably put all of them in quotes just for consistency if I did), but glad that helped in any case.

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially trying to map characters to their names and the result of `' '.toLowerCase() !== 'spc'`. The name is wrong, which is causing an exception to be thrown.

Changing the `spc` key to `' '` fixes the error, as [you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/9u3ez6gu/14/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this way works, it seems a little cleaner to go with T.J. Crowder's answer just because I think it's probably better practice and may prevent future bugs. I appreciate your help though so I voted you up. Thanks again.

Comment: @DigitalBrent we made the same changes, he just explained more thoroughly in his answer. ;)

Comment: He also recommended charCodeAt which I did not see in your answer. Still though, I always appreciate any help I get.

Comment: So he did. That's probably a better answer.

Comment: There's something to be said for succinctness, though. Your first sentence is wonderfully clear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
spc: []
```

with

```
' ': []
```